# hypertable filter by one cell, but bringing all column family

Tags: database, hypertable

Im trying to do something like this:

Select column1, column2 from mytable where column1 = 'wathever';

But I cannot find something similar for hypertable, I understand the architecture and that it handles individual rows, but I would like to know if that's possible, I want to filter by one column but bringing all column family.

Thanks in advance

Comment: With the lack of documentation, samples and my weak experience on this DB, I had to move this to mongoDB

Comment: The functionality of Select by condition is not available in Hypertable. May be in future it will be available.